# How do you add all that is left in the table in php after filtering it using ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to filter out the dates then add the amounts that are left.
Below is the code for the table which consists of amounts and date. There is an input which would ask for the date then filter them out.

```
<?php $total = 0; ?>
<table id="dateTable">
    <tr class="header">
        <th style="width:50%;">Amount</th>
        <th style="width:50%;">Date</th>
    </tr>
    @if ( count( $data['getBookValue'] ) )
        @foreach( $data['getBookValue'] as $book_value )
            @if ($book_value['status'] == 1)
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php $total += $book_value['amount']; ?>
                    <?php echo $book_value['amount']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $book_value['created_at']->format('m/d/Y'); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    @endif
</table>
```

This is the script

```
function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("event_date_range");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("dateTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to have a running total as you go.

Start a total variable at zero, and as you test each row, if the display is set to "", add the value to the total. Something like this:

```
totalViewable = 0;
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
  tds = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
  td = tds[1];
  if (td) {
    if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      tr[i].style.display = "";
      totalViewable += parseFloat(tds[0]);
    } else {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I used this instead
`totalViewable += parseFloat(tds.innerHTML);`
but thank you for giving me an idea